# Algorithm optimization - Find the unique number in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, optimization

The goal is to find the unique number in an array which contains identical numbers except one. Speed is of the essence as arrays can be huge. My code below works for smaller arrays but times out for large arrays. How to improve the algo? See input / output example below:

Input = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Output = 2

```
def find_uniq(arr):

    result = [x for x in arr if arr.count(x) ==1]
    return result[0]
```

Comment: Please include an example of an expected input and output (and improve the title!) Seems like you've confused a lot of people. :)

Comment: Apologies for failing to include an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is *quadratic*!

You can bring this down to linear, using `collections.Counter` in association with `next` (very handy when you don't want the entire list being built only to be thrown away). The counts are precomputed and then the first unique value found is returned.

```
from collections import Counter

def find_uniq(arr):
    c = Counter(arr)
    return next(x for x in arr if c[x] == 1)
```

`next` shines here because the goal is to return the first unique value found. `next` works with a generator, and only the first item is returned (further computation halts).

Comment: s/c[arr]/c[x]/ actually ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Wow, didn't see that blooper. Awkward! Thanks.

Comment: It will give the first unique value in list, am I right ?

Comment: @bhansa `The goal is to find the unique number in an array` so I am assuming only one exists. If more exist, only the first is found. The function, in any case should return an integer without unwanted computation. If you build the whole list, and return l[0], think about the case where you found the unique element at the beginning, but you ended up iterating through the whole list unnecessarily.

Comment: Gotcha! I got the same idea, I guess there is a way with bitwise as well but we need to traverse the whole array.

Comment: @bhansa Bitwise isn't a good idea when you have non-unique elements appearing an odd number of times.

Comment: fastest solution so far, but it might eat a lot of memory for really huge arrays.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers But you're iterating over the list, not the dict.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ oops - indeed, I missed that point #confused - edited my comment

Comment: timeit results (with a 202 elements list with 2 unique values and (2x)100 duplicated one), randomly shuffled, for 10000 calls: OP's solution averages at 3.00, coldspeed's solution at 0.50, which is a factor 6. My own "stupid" solution (cf my answer) ranges from 0.15 (best case) to 2.98 (worst case) depending on the source list.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for timing it! Best case? Maybe... what about the average and worst case?.. ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ your best case is =~ 0.45 and worst case =~ 0.67. Average I already mentionned is around 0.50 (well, around 0.55 for the last batch I ran).

Comment: Just to clarify that there is one unique element in the array.

Comment: @coldspeed can you please explain what exactly do you mean by quadratic? My understanding is that in my initial solution I had to count the number of occurrences of each element in the list (so n times). I also found a better solution that my initial one simply using a while loop (which stops as soon as a different number is found provided that the first number is not the one we were seeking to identify of course...)

Comment: @Steph_Golf - list.count is not a constant time operation. It is linear. You call count each time in the loop - it is extremely inefficient in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using NumPy:

```
np.where(np.bincount(arr) == 1)
```

Comment: There is no mention of numpy anywhere in the question, nor does this demonstrate any algorithmic techniques. Not sure why this answer has an upvote.

Comment: After a quick benchmark (using timeit and a randomly shuffled list with 2 unique values and 200 duplicated ones), it's constantly the slowest solution (slower than the OP's one).  NB : Python 2.7.6 on a debian-based distro.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the stupidiest solution is not the worst:

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    count = arr.count
    for x in arr:
        if count(x) == 1:
            return x
    return None
```

Depending on where the first unique item is, this can be faster or slower than than Coldspeed's `Counter` based solution (which seems mostly stable). In the worst case, it's only marginally faster than the OP's solution but eats less memory. In the best case it's obviously the winner ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution because it iterates over the Counter dictionary, not the original array (which will likely be longer) when trying to find the unique number/numbers. It will work with a Python `list` of integers or floats as the function input

```
from collections import Counter

def find_uniq(arr):
    return next(k for k,v in Counter(arr).items()
                if v == 1)
```

or if you may have more than one number with a count of 1:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_uniq(arr):
    return [k for k,v in Counter(arr).items()
            if v == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to find it quickly

```
def find_uniq(arr):

    members = list(set(arr))
    for member in members:
        if arr.count(member) == 1:
            return member
        continue
    return None #if there aren't any uniques
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have [@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196212/algorithm-to-find-the-unique-number-in-a-list/46196320#46196320) answer which is the fastest generic solution to this problem. Almost linear for any sorted or unsorted array.

> ```
> from collections import Counter
>
> def find_uniq(arr):
>     c = Counter(arr)
>     return next(x for x in arr if c[x] == 1)
> ```

Since the question is tagged [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) I want to show how you can still solve the problem with *linear* time complexity without any module, just yout algorithm:

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    i = 0
    while i < len(arr):
        j = i + 1
        pivot = arr[i] # store arr[i] so you don't have to access array again to read its value
        while j < len(arr) and pivot == arr[j]:
            j += 1
        if j - i == 1: # if previous loop never executed
            return pivot
        i = j
    return None
```

**About its complexity:** This is not only *O(n)*, it's also *Θ(n)* since `i = j` makes sure you don't access any array element more than **once**. Spatial complexity is *O(1)*.

**About its correctness:** It works only if input array is **sorted**! So here is the big deal. If you can build your array already sorted this algorithm will be faster than `Counter` and anything else. Problem is if the array is not already sorted you'll have to sort it. `arr.sort()` uses *Timsort* algorithm, which is *Ω(log(N!))*,*Θ(log(N!))* and *O(log(N!))*, with *O(n)* worst-case spatial complexity. Therefore in worst case (array not already sorted) the whole code will *O(log(N!))*. Still better than *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, though.

Answer (score -3):

```
R_dic = dict()
R = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
R_dic = {i: R.count(i) for i in R if i not in R_dic}  #list comprehension 
print R_dic
```

output:

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 1}
```

now check for the key and value in the dictionary as per your condition.

Comment: This is not a "list" comprehension, it's a dict comprehension - obviously... Also the first `R_dic = dict()` is totally useless.